# How should I build a character that exclusively uses bound weapons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am planning to make a Conjuration character that will only use bound weapons and their related perks. (No other conjuration perks will be needed, such the ones related to  summoned atronachs and raising the dead.)

My main source of damage will be the bow, followed by the battleaxe. I don't plan on using one-handed weapons, only the battleaxe and the bow.

Since I will not be able to upgrade any weapon that I will be using, nor enchant it, I can ignore most of the Smithing and Enchanting Perks.

**My Questions are :**

1. Which other trees would be useful for my path?
2. Should I use Heavy, Light, or Robes (No armor, alteration way of life)
3. Is it viable to play the game on Master difficulty using only conjured weapons as my main source of damage?

**Observations:**

I Have no problems in using mods such as "Better Conjuration Bounded Weapons" (which increases the "Mystic Binding" perk to 3/3 instead of 1/1) or "Bound Weapons Damage Scales With Conjuration" (which is self-explanatory) and that sort of thing.

Comment: Note: Bound weapons are great at low levels but get pretty weak at higher levels (especially once you get smithing to 100). See [wiki](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Bound_Weapon#Bound_Weapon_Damage)

Comment: @theJollySin That's semi-correct. One can still easily finish the game on master difficulty using bound weapons. That not only allows you to skip smothing all together, but also to play as a sort of melee-mage kind of character which is fun and has an interesting lore to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally speaking, as a weapon-using character, there's not going to be much difference between a bound weapon and a physical one. So, to answer your first question, the other trees useful to your path will be the same ones that are useful to *any* bow/battleaxe-wielding character.

As for armor choices, you might want to take a look at [this question about warrior armor types](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52191/best-armor-type-for-warrior-build), or [this one about two-handed warrior mages](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35450/what-armor-for-a-two-handed-battle-mage).

Finally, since bound weapons are [roughly equivalent in strength to Daedric weapons](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bound_Weapon), I see no reason why using them on Master difficulty wouldn't be viable.

Comment: Good answer. In addition to that: I recently found out that you can also apply poisons to bound weapons. Another reason to level alchemy for increased weapon effectiveness.

Answer (score 4):

You should fully upgrade the bound weapons part of the conjuration tree, and also upgrade 1-handed, 2-handed, and archery as these all contribute to your bound weapons. In my opinion, bound weapons are the best weapons in the game as they have the equivalent damage to daedric weapons and are weightless so it uses less stamina to power attack.

As far as the armor goes, if you want to keep with a magey type feel I would suggest Oakflesh, Stoneflesh, Ironflesh, or Eebonyflesh, and get the Mage Armor perks and use robes for good magicka regeneration and the decrease in cost. If you want the best armor rating possible, use a set of legendary daedric and enchant magicka regen on it .

Bound weapon logic: 
Bound battleaxe: 25 damage, weight 0. Tome cost 356 from Phinis Gestor
Ebony warhammer: 24 damage, weight 25. Need a high level to find, buy, smith.
Daedric battleaxe: 25 damage, weight 25. Cannot find, need REALLY high smith skill.

Answer (score -2):

You should get lv 100 smithing, make  full daedric set. (Everything) Smith all daedric items to Legendary. Then reset smithing to Lv 15 and gets perks back. The daedric sword should do about 50 damage without one handed perks.

Comment: except, the asker asks specifically in regards to *not* using daedric weapons. "How should I build a character that **exclusively** uses bound weapons?".

Comment: @Aaron Gornalle Also, why would I cheat and reset smithing stats ? That's bad :(